# How To Solve a Trigonometric Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, proof-explanation

Salutations, I have been trying to approach an ODE with trigonometric functions that I found interesting:

$$y'+x\sin(2y)=xe^{-x^2}\cos^2(y)$$

I tried to find a result with wolfram web page (free version) and I got this one:

$$y=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}(c+x^2)\right)$$

I have tried to approach this exercise by substitution of variables, also separable variables and I have not had luck by power series, 
and I do not know if methods like those of Ricatti and Bernoulli are appropriate for this case.

This is just for academic curiosity and I would like to understand better this kind of ODEs. So, I require any guidance or starting steps or explanations about how to approach this kind of exercises.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The answer mentions that this is an exercise.  Is that in fact correct?  If so, it would be helpful to know which section / chapter of the textbook this exercise comes from, since that would give a hint as to how to approach the problem.

Comment: Well, I saw this equation in a fb group named JulioProfe some time ago. I found the exercise interesting and decided to take it back a few days ago, I don't know the original textbook where the exercise came from and I got the answer from wolfram without initial steps of procedure. I tried the find alternative solutions or the answer given by wolfram, but I was not lucky until I wrote this post, That's all the story.

Comment: "I saw this problem on Facebook" is more promising than "This DE came up in a research problem I'm working on", since the latter wouldn't give any hope of being solvable.  One possibility for working backward once you get a solution is to isolate the arbitrary constant and then differentiate.  You may be able to work to the original DE, which would let you see how to solve it.  I am curious how Wolfram was able to solve this, however, since even Lutzl's solution requires enough experience to try dividing by $\cos^2 y$ and realizing that the result is an improvement.

Answer (score 16):

This is in general so non-linear that you can not expect a closed solution. However, as it is an exercise a closed solution most probably exists, so you have to consider the parts of this equation. With some experience one may see that dividing by $\cos^2y$ gives
$$
\frac{y'}{\cos^2 y}+2x\tan y=xe^{-x^2}
$$
which has the form 
$$
f'(y)y'+2xf(y)=xe^{-x^2}
$$
which now is linear in $u=f(y)=\tan(y)$. For this linear equation, $e^{x^2}$ is an integrating factor which miraculously also simplifies the right side. After integrating you get
$$
e^{x^2}\tan(y(x))=\frac12x^2+c.
$$

Comment: Thanks very much for your commentary, I was taking unnecessary and hard paths to solve this exercise, thanks again for your explanation, the substitution of tangent function was very helpful, thanks for all.

Comment: @ht1204 You can accept the answer to indicate that it is the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, the solution that I wrote was given by Wolfram, I saw this exercise in a fb group, I don't know the origin  textbook, So, I wrote this post to find help if it was the correct solution or there was an alternative solution, that was my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

When I saw the equation which contains $\sin(2y)$ and $\cos^2(y)$, I immediately thought about the tangent hal-angle subsitution (let us call that *intuition*).

So, let $y=\tan ^{-1}(z)$ which reduces the equation to
$$z'+2 x z=e^{-x^2} x$$ The homogeneous part is simple
$$z'+2 x z=0 \implies z=C \,e^{-x^2}$$
Now, variation of parameters to get 
$$C'=x \implies C=\frac 12 x^2+c_1\implies z=e^{-x^2}\left(\frac 12 x^2+c_1 \right)$$ and, finally, the solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your commentary, it's an interesting point of view about how to solve the equation, thanks very much.